# How to display graphical layout previews for different user selected display font sizes

Tags: android, adt, layout-editor

**BACKGROUND:**
The ADT (ver 21) allows preview thumbnails for various displays.
Android allows the user to select a small/normal/large/huge font size in Settings->Display.
The Android setting may affect the display setting, requiring additional design considerations.

**QUESTION:**
Is there a way to preview a "Normal" display font selection, as well as a "Huge" font selection?

Comment: This question should be closed because ADT is obsolete.